# Should the tag phpdocumenter be renamed to phpdocumentor?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've noticed that the tag [phpdocumenter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phpdocumenter) is not spelt correctly however I'm not sure if I'm right or wrong on that.

That said, on the [phpdocumentor](https://www.phpdoc.org) offical site it's spelt phpdocumentor *not* phpdocumenter. Note the *e*.

Should [phpdocumenter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phpdocumenter) be renamed to [phpdocumentor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phpdocumentor)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phpdocumentor2

Comment: @yivi see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phpdocumenter

Comment: I know, but I have no idea what that other tag is. Maybe you wanted to use `phpdocumentor2` instead?

Comment: I do not know if it refers to some historic old version, or just some people using the wrong spelling/tag. (As it happened to you).

Comment: I wanted to know that is it correct `phpdocumenter`?

Comment: If it is wrong spelling/tag, than I think it should be renamed...

Comment: Did you want to tag about something called `phpdocumenter`, or about something called `phpdocumentor2`? If you wanted the latter, use the latter tag.

Comment: both are looking correct and have a same purpose... I have an issue with tag spell, I Google it but not found any satisfied results on `phpdocumenter` is correct spelling or not?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[phpdocumentor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phpdocumentor) exists as a synonym of [phpdoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phpdoc) (which actually represents PHPDoc, of which phpDocumentor is the official implementation). The canonical phpDocumentor tag is therefore [phpdoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phpdoc).

I just created a synonym mapping the misspelled "phpdocumenter" (with an e) tag to the canonical tag so the problem should go away now.